# Android: disable SD card/ do not allow mounting of the SD card

Tags: android

I need to prevent a phone from having its firmware/ ROM updated. I already disabled lots of stuff like USB debugging, but people can still go to the recovery mode by pressing Vol+ and rebooting the device and then flash a new firmware from the SD card. 
Can I somehow disable the SD card slot completely without physical changes to the device or writing my own firmware?

Comment: If you write codes on OS App level, you can't control things on firmware level / recovery mode .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow disable the SD card slot completely without physical changes to the device or writing my own firmware?

Fortunately, no.